# PHPUnit Code Coverage False Positives?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, code-coverage

I ran phpunit with code coverage in order to see which ones of my classes are less tested.

I arbitrarily excluded some folders such as `DataFixtures` (Doctrine fixtures) and `Admin` (Sonata Admin classes) and this is the result:

[image]

I noticed that the `Entity` folder is all in red but it contains only classes with a lot of standard getters and setters. Same thing for the `Model` folder.

How can I test them **without ignoring**?

Comment: Are you asking how to test a class with a bunch of getters and setters and not much more? In that case, you could write a test that sets and a value and then gets it back and checks if it's unchanged. I don't know PHP well enough to know if that can be done in a generic way. Such tests are *usually* of very low value and it tends to be better to just live without 100% coverage.

Comment: Yes, these class are only entities with fields, getters and setters. The actual methods are tested. So I could exclude the Entity folder as well?

Comment: I would say that writing tests for a bunch of data objects is a massive waste of time but in the end it's up to you what you want to exclude or not. That comes down to opinion. But are you asking if you should exclude the folder now or is the question still about how to test an object with mostly getters and setters?

Comment: I came here via meta btw, so I haven't voted on the question, but I'm getting slowly more confused about what you're asking now :) Maybe you should add a bit more detail into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit offers some ways to modify how coverage is tracked using annotations on yor tests, such as `@covers` and `@coversNothing`. You can also exclude sections of your code from coverage by using `@codeCoverageIgnore`. How to use them is covered in the docs: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

When running the tests you can use [command line options](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions) to modify some of those settings:

```
--strict-coverage           Be strict about @covers annotation usage.
--disable-coverage-ignore   Disable annotations for ignoring code coverage.
```

If your problem does not stem from limiting coverage on those entities, you should identify which tests use them to see if the methods are actually called. I could imagine that you have mocked them and that is why they are not covered.